# Spring Boot: how to disable (or remove) property in application.properties using externalized configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project (v2.3.x) connected to a MongoDB instance.

The connection is configured using the property `spring.data.mongodb.uri`.

Now, for local development I'd like to configure the connection using host/port, i.e. using these properties (I'm configuring these via ENV VARs):

```
spring.data.mongodb.host
spring.data.mongodb.port
```

Adding these properties, while leaving `spring.data.mongodb.uri`, obviously results in an error on application run:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials/replicaSet must be specified
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to disable the `spring.data.mongodb.uri` configuration using properties override (externalized configuraion) provided by Spring Boot.

Is this possible? I tried setting `spring.data.mongodb.uri=null` but the startup error remains.

How can I achieve this without directly modifying the `application.properties` file?

**NOTE**: I also considered using *profiles*, but also using this feature I cannot find a way to override the "main" configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "application-default.properties" file and put `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in there. The "default" Spring profile will be active when no other profiles are selected. So you can start locally with any profile ("dev" or whatever) and "application-default.properties" file will not be loaded.

Of course, keep in mind that adding any profile in production would also disable `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in this case.